# Install error for NacL ports for SDL

Tags: sdl, google-nativeclient

When I want to install NaClports for SDL I got an error on the "./make_all.sh sdl" input

Here is the tutorial : 
https://code.google.com/p/naclports/wiki/InstallingSDL

Here is the error :

```
boufle@Coucou:~/naclports/src$ ./make_all.sh sdl
+ set -e
+ TARGETS=sdl
+ TARGETS=sdl
+ export BUILD_FLAGS=--ignore-disabled
+ export NACL_ARCH=x86_64
+ export TOOLCHAIN=glibc
+ make sdl
build_tools/naclports.py install sdl --ignore-disabled
Building 'zlib' [x86_64/glibc]
chdir /home/boufle/naclports/src/out/build/zlib/zlib-1.2.8
sha1check.py: zlib-1.2.8.tar.gz verified
######################################################################
Skipping extract step
######################################################################
chdir /home/boufle/naclports/src/out/build/zlib/zlib-1.2.8
######################################################################
Skipping patch step (cleaning source tree)
######################################################################
Removing configure.log
######################################################################
Configuring zlib
######################################################################
chdir /home/boufle/naclports/src/out/build/zlib/zlib-1.2.8
rm -f libz.*
CPPFLAGS=-I/home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/include
CFLAGS= -O2
CXXFLAGS= -O2
LDFLAGS=-L/home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/lib/glibc_x86_64/Release -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/lib/glibc_x86_64/Release -L/home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/x86_64-nacl/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/x86_64-nacl/usr/lib
./configure --prefix=/naclports-dummydir
Using /home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-ar
Using /home/boufle/nacl_sdk/pepper_34/toolchain/linux_x86_glibc/bin/x86_64-nacl-ranlib
Using x86_64-nacl-nm
Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror).
** ./configure aborting.
naclports: Building 'zlib' failed.
make: *** [sdl] Erreur 1
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 7 64bits with pepper_34.
Build-essential is installed.

Comment: I'm trying to install zlib on Windows and similarly get the "Compiler error reporting is too harsh for ./configure (perhaps remove -Werror)." so seems this is not OS specific. If you look at the "./configure" file in zlib this shell script seems to cause the error:
`if try $CC -c $CFLAGS $test.c; then
  :
else
  echo "Compiler error reporting is too harsh for $0 (perhaps remove -Werror)." | tee -a configure.log
  leave 1
fi`

Comment: Not resolved .. :(